# php not echoing html

Tags: php, html

i have a table which is not showing, its showing the actual text. Here is the code:

```
<?php $form ="<form action='log.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>username</td>
<td>input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password</td>
<td>input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td></td>
<td>input type='submit' name='login' vaue='submit' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";
?>
```

It is not out-putting the table or the submit button or input area. Any suggestions why? 
Im using ubuntu with apache installed, normal tables, forms work and php is working but not when i try to output HTML using php its shows actual HTML and not its properties.

Comment: Because you just assign the string to `$form`. You haven't echo'd the contents.

Comment: print the variable `echo $form;`

Comment: Also, 4rth from bottom line is `<td>input type='submit' name='login' vaue='submit' /></td>`, should be `<td><input type='submit' name='login' value='submit' /></td>`, remember to open your html tags ;P Just saw that the same is for **ALL** inputs, blatant copy-paste mistake here! Also, there is no attribute `vaue`, I think you meant `value` :)

Comment: @SamSwift good catch on the `vaue` and missing `<`. Many answers given below did not catch that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I just read the code and something didn't make sense, also helps that I am using Visual Studio with (IMO) the best syntax highlighting around, I copied the code, removed the PHP 'taggy' bits and saw what didn't look right within a second!

Comment: @SamSwift most likely the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some html tag errors. Input tags html code was not proper. Replace with this and use echo() method to print $form variable's value.

```
<?php $form ="<form action='log.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>username</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password</td>
<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='login' value='submit' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";
echo $form;
?>
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: `vaue`, syntax error that you copied from OP's code, invalid syntax.

Comment: Ah this worked finally its displaying. May be some tag errors causing the problem, which can be hard to notice. THANKS.

Comment: @AmitRajput, perfection is a cruel mistress ;P

Answer (score 2):

Remove echo and php tags itself.

```
<form action='log.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>username</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password</td>
<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='login' value='submit' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: still missing a few `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks about alright, just one thing you're missing and that's the following:

```
echo $form;
```

In order to print anything on your webpage, you use `echo` followed by a value or variable.

Comment: if i put $form; i get blank white screen

Comment: `echo $form;`, not `$form;`. Are you sure you used `echo` correctly?

Comment: you missed a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to do something like this:

```
<?php
function ShowHtml()
{
?>
<form action='log.php' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>username</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='user' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>password</td>
            <td>
                <input type='password' name='password' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='submit' name='login' value='submit' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

This removes the need to do an `echo` or `print` and also fixes your syntax errors(namely missing `<` tags and the `vaue` that should be `value`).

Also in this you could have a function such as:

```
<?php
function ShowHtml($html)
{
    if ($html != null || $html != '' || !empty($html)) # Just a check to make sure then html is set ;P
    {
        print $html; # could use echo instead, personal preference :)
                     # Could also add more validation to make sure the html tags themselves are valid and correct
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Or you could do (keeping the PHP surround):

```
<?php
$form = "<form action='log.php' method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>username</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='user' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>password</td>
            <td>
                <input type='password' name='password' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type='submit' name='login' value='submit' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>";

echo $form; # Or print, your choice :) 
            # Can also use the bracketed way of echo(...) 
            # or print(...) for an added layer of 
            # 'make sure I only print what I want to'
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote Sam: `if ($html != null && $html != '' && !empty($html))` should be `||`'s ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I use the `&&` simply because it gives the extra layer of security because if any one of the conditions (in the order given) are met, then the function with process where this way **EVERY** eventuality is covered, I like the extra security ;P

Comment: `&&` checks for `AND`, I doubt that a variable can contain `null` AND `nothing` AND is empty and be checked for all those conditions using `&&`; think about it. Unless I'm not catching ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, good point, great point in fact! I shall amend to show this!

Comment: *wishing I knew how to nominate @Fred-ii- for mod!*

Comment: *perfetto* - *cheers* Sam. Me, mod? *ha ha!* How many these days want me to be a mod. They're not ready for me lol. They're looking for German Shepherds, not a "Pitbull" ;-) but thanks. It's a bigger "job" that many don't think. I like my "freedom" heh.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, it certainly seems to be a huge job, one I don't think I'd be able to handle at all, but from your frequency on questions and the answers/comments that you give to people both in a friendly and professional manner, I think you **ARE** the perfect candidate for mod :-P

Comment: Sure, if they paid me for it lol. I do have a "day job", somewhat. heh thanks Sam, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

use `echo`  like that :-

```
<?php 
$form ="<form action='log.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>username</td>
<td><input type='text' name='user' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password</td>
<td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td></td>
<td><input type='submit' name='login' value='submit' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";
echo $form;
?>
```

or change this `input` to this `<input`